# How to print value from database

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am trying to add new functionality to Storelocator module. I
have added new checkbox in admin and create new column in database
table. Saving checkbox value to databse is working. Now I want to print "recommended" value, but nothing happens. Why?

Checkbox field /Sparx/Storelocator/Block/Adminhtml/Storelocator/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('recommended', 'checkbox', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('storelocator')->__('Recommended'),
      'onclick'   => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'recommended',
      'value'     => '0',
  ));
```

Printing value /Sparx/Storelocator/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<div class="list-content">
<div class="loc-name">{{name}}</div>
<div>{{recommended}}</div>
<div class="loc-addr">{{address}}</div> 
<div class="loc-addr3">{{city}}, {{state}} {{country}} {{postal}}</div> 
<div class="loc-phone">{{phone}}</div>
<div class="loc-web"><a href="http://{{web}}" target="_blank">{{web}}</a></div>
{{#if distance}}<div class="loc-dist">{{distance}} {{length}}</div>
<div class="loc-directions"><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={{origin}}&amp;daddr={{address}} {{city}}, {{state}} {{country}} {{postal}}" target="_blank">Directions</a></div>{{/if}}
{{#if storeid}}<div class="loc-desc"><a href="'. Mage::helper('storelocator')->getDetailpageUrl('{{storeid}}').'">Store Details</a></div>{{/if}}
```